# In MySQL, I can see 2 ids in one table while assigning index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

In PHPMyadmin, I am assigning index for `cus_id`.
But, in original table there is only 1 `id` field.

Why is it showing 2 `ids`?
[image]

Comment: is there an id key in your customers table?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling this is a 'submit to phpmyadmin creaters as a bug' solution?  From my experience, phpmyadmin has these issues consistantly, I defaulted to using mysql workbench for indexing in the past.

Comment: @Twelfth Just to confirm the feeling. I'm 70% sure it's a bug on PMAs end. Inspect your table to ensure that there is only a single column named id (silly, but double check).. If not, head over to PMA and submit a bug report

Comment: I think, you are right. It's weird problem.

Comment: I dont think it`s showind 2 ids,its just the drop down showing the currently selected AND the available values.I would also recommend Heidisql.

Comment: @DarylGill: I checked it again. there is only one `id` in `customers` table.

Comment: @Mihai: no. that's not the case here.

Comment: yea just select everything from the table if its not in there then submit the bug

Comment: Can I suggest uninstalling MySQL and installing something functional like Postgres as a valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Actually, I added 2 indexes on `id` column in customers table.
One is `PRIMARY` and other is `UNIQUE`. I have removed `UNIQUE` from that column.
Thanks for your efforts.